# Modeless form doesn't receive the input focus

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a Windows Form ("form1") which is opened with `ShowDialog()` in the main thread of application just before `Application.Run()` is called ( without that form as the argument ). From the main thread another thread ("thread2") is created, which runs in parallel with the main thread. With pressing a button in the "form1", another form ("form2") is created in the "thread2" and shown with `Show()` method. The problem: the "form2" doesn't get the input focus and doesn't receive keyboard or mouse input.

The form2 is created as follows:

```
public form2( )
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.SetStyle( ControlStyles.Selectable, true );
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
}
```

I created a handler on OnFocusLosing event which writes a string to the console, and see that the form2 is losing focus just after creation. Is it the form1, which is opened with `ShowDialog()` and runs in the main thread grabs the focus back? I tried to minimize the form1 before creating the form2, but it doesn't help.

How one can get a form to receive the input focus?

Comment: Google the term "modal".  It's what `ShowDialog` does.

Comment: Yes, with ShowDialog it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is only ever a single UI thread in a Windows Forms application, you can't just spawn off threads and expect the user to be able to interact with them.

You could try this if you really need two independent UI threads: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f0e7794-8671-47c4-aa9a-3bd1f85c9963/how-to-create-a-winform-app-with-two-ui-threads